# set the UIScrollview(on UICollectionViewCell) constraints but failed

Tags: ios, iphone

I put one UIScrollView on an UICollectionViewCell
[image]

I hope it automatically spread to fit to the screen width(uicollectionview width)

I set the constrains as below, but the green block does not spread.

I checked and found that UICollectionView does not fit the screen width

Is there a constraint for this?

Your comment welcome

[image]

Comment: set a background color to your uicollectionviewcell. and check again. did you do that?

Comment: yes but uicollectionviewcell does not auto fit the screen width, it can be done using code, just wonder if there is a way to make the uicollectionviewcell auto fit the screen/collectionview width

Comment: your question changed then. the problem is not with the uiscrollview any more. right??